# Add a static template to my typo3 extension

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid

I have created an extension with sitepackagebuilder.com and the idea is just to write some static html.
I know that when you have a controller you can call the templates by following the convention names. But what if you don't have a controller? What I need, at least for now, is just to install the extension, add the plugin into a page and get some static content in that page.
I can imagine that this is set in a typoscript file but I'm quite noob with all the typoscript thing.

I'm getting this error:
'No Content Object definition found at TypoScript object path "tt_content.list.20.heboorganigram_organigram"'

Until I define that object in my typoscript file. I have tried this.

```
tt_content.list.20.heboorganigram_organigram = PAGE
tt_content.list.20.heboorganigram_organigram.10 = TEMPLATE //(or FLUIDTEMPLATE same result)
tt_content.list.20.heboorganigram_organigram.10.template = FILE
tt_content.list.20.heboorganigram_organigram.10.template.file = fileadmin/Organigram.html
```

And then I don't get an error but I also don't get the content from my Organigram.html, this is just trying stuffs, I actually don't know if this is what I need to do.

Comment: "*But what if you don't have a controller?*" just create it, it priceless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before creating new Content Elements you first have to create the Page Template, for that have a look at the sitepackage tutorial https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-sitepackage/master/en-us/FluidTemplates/Index.html

If you already got the page template, have a look at https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/ContentElements/AddingYourOwnContentElements.html

Provided you already did the steps above, for getting the frontend output you are interested in the step `Configure the frontend rendering`

So the TypoScript should look something like this:

```
lib.contentElement {
    templateRootPaths.200 = EXT:heboorganigram/Resources/Private/Templates/
}
```

```
tt_content {
    examples_newcontentelement =< lib.contentElement
    examples_newcontentelement {
        templateName = NewContentElement
    }
}
```

Then you need to place your Organigram.html file in the Templates Folder in inside the sitepackage.

Comment: Hey man, thanks. Yes, I get it now, I NEED to create a custom content element, and that makes sense.